# Memory issues with QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qstring

I'm trying to use a QTextEdit to output a QstringList

e.g

```
void CTextBox::AddText(QStringList list, QStringList animList)
{
    //CGraphics* graphics = CGraphics::GetInst();

    //QStandardItem *baseItem = new StandardItem("Hello");
    //textBrowser = new QTextEdit();
    standardModel->clear();
    rootNode = standardModel->invisibleRootItem();
    treeView->setModel(standardModel);

    QString string;

    //std::string = list[i].

    QDataStream* data = new QDataStream;

    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (list.size()); i++)
    {
        //string += list[i];
        //string += hierarchyList[i];
        // textBrowser->setText(string);
        string.append(list[i]);
        //textBrowser->append(list[i]);

        if (list[i].contains("Is Parent"))
        {
            standardItems[j] = new QStandardItem(list[i-1]);
            /*for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                if (standardItems[j]->contains(st))
                   {
                   }
            }*/
            rootNode->appendRow(standardItems[j]);       
            //k = j;     
            j++;
        }
        else if (list[i].contains("inherits from"))
        {
            standardItems[j] = new QStandardItem(list[i-1]);
            for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                if (standardItems[k]->text() ==list[i+1])
                {
                    standardItems[k]->appendRow(standardItems[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //standardItems[k]->appendRow(standardItems[j]);
            j++;            
        }
        //textBrowser->setText("Hello");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (animList.size()); i++)
    {
        string.append(animList[i]);
        //textBrowser->append(animList[i]);
    }

    textBrowser->setText(string);

    treeView->setModel(standardModel);
    //CGraphics* graphics = CGraphics::GetInst();
    //graphics->Render();
}
```

But the size of the list can be absolutely enormous up to like 1700 lines. After about 400ish appends or so I get this error message.

> Unhandled exception at 0x65154715 in ipodGuiLoaderQT.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfe11.

This would usually indicate that there a memory overflow, but I can't control the memory of a textBrowser, or am I on the completely wrong track?

EDIT

I've made a small change, I'm now adding the list elements to a Qstring called string and then setting the text at the end of the loop.

e.g

```
textBrowser->setText(string);
```

I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: How do you know the access violation is related to this `textBrowser->append(list[i]);` call ? Did you use a debugger to track down the access violation ?

Comment: Yes basically when in my windows debugger I try to step over that line, it crashes and I get the pop up.

Comment: Is it crashing inside append() or operator[]() ?

Comment: Well, you should split this call in 2 : (1) access the i-th element of the list (btw check the value of `i` and make sure it's not out-of bounds). (2) append the string to text textEdit. Please update your question to give the context of this call.

Comment: The value of i is definately not out of bounds, it works for smaller lists and I've now setting the text outside the loop so it should crash in the for loop if it was a problem with i.

Comment: And I don't really know what you mean Alan by append() and operator[]()?

Comment: still, there is not enough code to know what is going on :). Please paste the whole context, maybe you deleted something or just made an out-of-bound access somewhere else

Comment: ok there : `for (int i = 0; i < (list.size()); i++)`, but you access the `i+1` : `list[i+1]`. This is an out-of-bound access

Comment: I'm guessing your talking about this: if (standardItems[k]->text() ==list[i+1]).  All it's doing is checking if the text is the same as i+1 if it's invalid then the condition won't trigger. And why wouldn't I have the same problem with a smaller list? Using the text visualizer I can see that the text in string is as it should be.

Comment: I can't tell from the Qt docs, but if it acts like standard containers, you could replace `[]` with `at()` and get an exception if it's actually an out of bounds index.

Comment: You can call `value()` and pass it a ridiculous default value for if the index is out of bounds and check for it that way.  Or you could use your debugger better.

Comment: @keith.layne My debugger sucks! Visual studio is no help. It's nothing to do with index. As I say it works with smaller lists fine. It gets to the 419th elepment out of 425on one list and then crashes when trying to append element 419, I can't even step in to the function without it crashing and the call stack is no help i can't even get back to the the function that makes it crash.

Comment: look : for **ALL** `i` in your first loop, I repeat : **FOR ALL** `i` value, you try to access `[i-1]` or `[i+1]`. This has to be the cause of the crash. Just find a way to access only in-bounds, or at least add some check tests before accessing the list anywhere like you do. As a matter of fact, the use of the `QList::at(int)` method is recommended in your case, as noted before by _keith.lane_

Comment: @totem, apologies for the delay. I don't access i-1 or i+1 in all iterations because of the if check before (list[i].contains("inherits from")). the earliest that it could even be accessed is loop 1  because the list always has a name of a sprite first then either the strings 'inherit from' or 'is a parent sprite'. This would mean the earliest element that can be compared element 0 is being checked which shouldn't cause an issue.  I'm also now using list.at(i-1) and list.at(i+1) for my checks and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `ith` element you are trying to append to the `QTextEdit` is a valid list element. Be carefuls when using the `[]` operator:

> Returns the item at index position i as a modifiable reference. i must
>   be a valid index position in the list (i.e., 0 <= i < size()).

If `i` is greater or equal to `list.count()` then this is probably the root of your crash.

In order to check that there is no problem with the `QTextEdit` you could try the following:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<50000; i++)
    textBrowser->append("Dummy String Row");
```

If the above code causes exception (I find it impossible) let us know. Otherwise there should be a problem with the list itself or more probably your code that handles the list.

**EDIT : SOME PROBLEMS CONCERNING YOUR CODE**

```
standardItems[j] = new QStandardItem(list[i-1]);
```

if `i==0` the `list[-1]` is invalid and a possible cause of crash

```
if (standardItems[k]->text() ==list[i+1])
```

Similarly if `i==list.count()-1` the `i+1` is not a valid index, so another cause of exception

**LOOPING THOUGH A `QStringList`**

In order to get all elements of a `QStringList` called `list` and display them on a `QTextEdit` you can do the following:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<list.count(); i++)
    textBrowser->append(list[i]);
```

This will work fine.

Comment: ok the test loop you've suggested worked fine.  So there's obviously some issue with the list then?

Comment: either the list or some other part of your code. How do you loop through the stringlist?

Comment: As in how do i add elements to the list?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? to get all elements of a QStringList and append them to a textedit?

Comment: To get all elements of a Qstringlist and display them in a Qtextedit. It works with smaller files that I can load e.g. 70 or 80 strings but not with anything big e.g. 400 and above.

Comment: And I'm also then trying to create a tree view of a hierachy.

Comment: ok standardItems[j] = new QStandardItem(list[i-1]); is not a problem because the if statement preceding it means it can never enter. I create the strings myself in another class so know that it can never contain "is parent". I've also tried taking 1 off the loop to see if it would work and it still doesn't so listi+1 isn't the problem either. And your last point was what I was doing before but I wanted a string to be able to check if the string being created is correct which it is.

Comment: It crashes on loop 419 out of 425 elements from one file.

Answer (score 0):

I open an answer here not to overload the comment list :)
If you are sure the problem does not come from the contents of `list` then it may be related to `standardItems` array. Could you tell how it's initialized ? Maybe you try to access it out of its bounds

Comment: Yeah... I've just realised my problem. My standarditems array was no where near big enough. Cheers.